# making my flex columns responsive for all screens, the html text overlaps into the next section and the column height seems to be shorter?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, responsive-design, media-queries

Hey guys I've been working on my portfolio site, and it is responsive for mobile, my Macbook Air
and both of my desktop monitors. but for some reason on my Lenovo laptop, the columns seem shorter and the text goes beyond the column length. Do I need another media query of is there something I need to fix in my css? Here is a screenshot
[screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Off2F.png)

here is the code, the media query has a min-width of 700px

```
 #skills .container {
        max-width: 1200px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 20px;
        height: 70vh;
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px rgba(57,56, 61, 0.205);
        display: flex;
        /* -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        flex-grow: 1; */
        
    }

    #skills .container .column {
        display: block;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        flex-basis: 33%;
        border-bottom: 0px solid #e2e2e2;
        border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
        /* margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px; */
    }

    #skills .container .column:last-child {
        border-right: none;
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    #skills .container .column #skills-icon{
        margin: 20px 20px;
        font-size: 35px;
        color: #6666ff;

  
    }

    #skills .container .card p {
        font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the `height: 70vh;` on your `#skills .container` selector.

Your laptop screen likely has a lower vertical resolution and 70% of that isnt enough to display the content of your skills container.

Try changing this to `min-height: 70vh;`, that way it can be taller if required by the content.

Comment: I tried that it did not work it is still messed up on the Lenovo laptop.

Comment: Did it change anything?

Comment: yes i did fit it some what by adding a media query for the max height of the lenovo laptop, giving it a max height of 768px.